# Regex word boundry

Tags: java, regex

I am splitting a string by word boundary.

What I am expecting is:

```
 TOKEN 0  
 TOKEN 1 0
 TOKEN 2  
 TOKEN 3 +Ve
```

and, what I am getting is,

```
 TOKEN 0  
 TOKEN 1 0
 TOKEN 2  +
 TOKEN 3 Ve



public void StringExample(){
    String str = " 0 +Ve";

    String[] token = str.split("\\b");

    System.out.println("TOKEN 0 " + token[0]);
    System.out.println("TOKEN 1 " + token[1]);
    System.out.println("TOKEN 2 " + token[2]);
    System.out.println("TOKEN 3 " + token[3]);
}
```

Can someone give a clue where its going wrong? and Possible corrections if any,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is going wrong, and the results are as should be expected. Word boundaries match at the before the first character of a String, after the last character of a String and *between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character*. The last rule will result in a match between '+' and 'V', and so your results make perfect sense.

Perhaps you want to use look ahead and look behind to match anything next to a space. For example:

```
public class Foo001 {
   // private static final String REGEX1 = "\\b";
   private static final String REGEX2 = "(?= )|(?<= )";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String str = " 0 +Ve";

      String[] tokens = str.split(REGEX2);
      for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
         System.out.printf("token %d: \"%s\"%n", i, tokens[i]);
      }

   }
}
```

This will also match the left of the first space giving an extra token:

```
token 0: ""
token 1: " "
token 2: "0"
token 3: " "
token 4: "+Ve"
```

Answer (score 3):

Both @pb2q and @Hovercraft have already explained why word boundary doesn't work in your situation. An alternative, is to use a `Pattern` and capture each group, which will give you what you want:

```
String str = " 0 +Ve";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("( |[^ ]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
  tokens.add(m.group(1));
}           
System.out.println("TOKEN 0 " + tokens.get(0));
System.out.println("TOKEN 1 " + tokens.get(1));
System.out.println("TOKEN 2 " + tokens.get(2));
System.out.println("TOKEN 3 " + tokens.get(3));
```

Comment: thanks, joao.  Your solution is what i looking for, but little extra bit of lines have to be written.  I go for Hovercraft's solution

Comment: @Firmview: Joao's solution is a very good one, perhaps better than mine. 1+

Answer (score 1):

`+` is not counted as a word char for word boundaries. Word chars are `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, that is, alphanumeric, and underscore

Unless your strings get more complex than your example, this is another instance where you can just split around the space:

```
" 0 +Ve".split(" ");
```

This should yield this array: `[" ", "0", "+Ve"]`.

Which doesn't quite match the token list that you expect, but may suit your purposes. With this token list you know that there is a leading space character, and you can infer a space as the third token.

A problem with splitting this way is that multiple space characters will yield additional `" "` tokens in the resulting array.

Comment: No, that will give only three tokens.

Comment: thanks, @pb2q.  Your solution gives very nice alternative.  I go for Hovercraft's solution